# Struts2 Tags Radio button

Tags: java, forms, struts2, radio-button

I have this iterator that loops through an object.

```
        <s:iterator value = "choices" status = "key">
        <s:set var = "test" value ="%{#key.index}"/>
             <input type = "radio" name="choices[{key.index}].answer" />
             <s:textfield name = "choices[%{#key.index}].value" value = "%{choices[%{#key.index}].value}"/>
            <br>
        </s:iterator>
```

where `answer` is a boolean value, that I am trying to set through radio buttons.

but the problem is, upon on the generated html, teh radio buttons. is like this

```
<input type = "radio" name="choices[%{#key.index}].answer" />
```

It did not have the indice/index. it only gave me the `%{#key.index}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use property tag to get the actual value

```
<input type = "radio" name="<s:property value='%{choices[#key.index].answer}' />" />
```

Better use radio tag of struts tag library, like this

```
<s:radio name="choices[%{#key.index}].answer" / >
```

Comment: still wrong :) you are missing quotation marks, and doubling the %{} notation that should not be nested

Comment: Yeah :) I've never uesed single quotation mark in struts tags, but i guess it works... and you can do the reverse for sure (single in name=, double in s:property). You can even use double quotation mark for name= and s:property, it will mess up Eclipse but it is valid, because once processed the s:property won't be there anymore :)